# How to add Glue Table with struct type column using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-athena, aws-glue, amazon-cloudtrail

I am enabling Athena to query on Cloudtrail s3 logs using Terraform.
To do this, I need to create database and tables in Glue Catalog.
I am following this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html).

In Terraform I am using `aws_glue_catalog_table resource`.
How can I define columns with type struct and Array in terraform file?

I tried defining below ways but did not work.

```
  resource "aws_glue_catalog_database" "cloud_logs" {
    name = "trail_logs_db"
  }

  resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "cloud_table" {
    name          = "trail_logs"
    database_name = "${aws_glue_catalog_database.cloud_logs.name}"

    table_type = "EXTERNAL_TABLE"

    parameters = {
      EXTERNAL = "TRUE"
    }

    storage_descriptor {
      location      = "s3://<BUCKET NAME>/AWSLogs/<AWS ACCOUNT ID>/"
      input_format  = "com.amazon.emr.cloudtrail.CloudTrailInputFormat"
      output_format = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"

      ser_de_info {
        name                  = "trail-logs"
        serialization_library = "com.amazon.emr.hive.serde.CloudTrailSerde"

        parameters {
          serialization.format = 1
        }
      }

      columns = [
        {
          name = "useridentity"
          type = "struct<type:string,
                 principalid:string,
                 arn:string,
                 accountid:string,
                 invokedby:string,
                 accesskeyid:string,
                 userName:string,>"
          comment = ""
        },
        {
          name    = "resources"
          type    = "array<STRUCT<ARN:string,
                    accountId:string,
                    type:string>>"
          comment = ""
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

WHen I run `terraform init` It throws below error:
`Error: Error parsing test.tf: At 33:27: illegal char`

Comment: Can you share an [mcve] of your Terraform code and also explain more clearly what you mean by "did not work"? Did it error? If so edit your question to include the full error output. If it did something you were not expecting explain the result of the Terraform code and what you wanted instead.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Thanks, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Found workaround, It does not look good though.

It works when I format it in one line.

```
  {
     name = "useridentity"
     type = "struct<type:string, principalid:string, arn:string, accountid:string,  invokedby:string, accesskeyid:string, userName:string,>"
      comment = ""
  },
  {
     name    = "resources"
     type    = "array<STRUCT<ARN:string, accountId:string, type:string>>"
     comment = ""
  },
```

Comment: for me the multiline version doesn't work at all. only in a single line, does it accept the resources...

Comment: also, for me the type string my not contain any capital letters or spaces.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [heredoc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#string-literals):

```
    {
          name = "useridentity"
          type = <<- EOT
                 struct<type:string,
                 principalid:string,
                 arn:string,
                 accountid:string,
                 invokedby:string,
                 accesskeyid:string,
                 userName:string,>
                 EOT
          comment = ""
        },
        {
          name    = "resources"
          type    = <<- EOT
                    array<STRUCT<ARN:string,
                    accountId:string,
                    type:string>>
                    EOT
          comment = ""
        },
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert.
I tried but it is showing in change in resource.. 
 
Expected way --> "array<struct<ARN:string,accountId:string,type:string>>"
Actual ==> "array<struct<ARN:string,\naccountId:string,\ntype:string>>\n"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use join for this:

```
type = join(",", ["struct<type:string",
                  "principalid:string",
                  "arn:string",
                  "accountid:string",
                  "invokedby:string",
                  "accesskeyid:string",
                  "userName:string>"])
```